# Android : Can't import ViewRoot

Tags: android

I'm writing an app where I want to start with a `View` object and walk up the `View` hierarchy, using `getParent()` until I get all the way to `ViewRoot`, which I hope to detect using `instanceof`.

Seems simple enough, but I'm in trouble already because I can't seem to import `ViewRoot`. On the line where I have:

```
import android.view.ViewRoot;
```

I get:

> The import android.view.ViewRoot cannot be resolved

I've written dozens of apps in this environment, importing everything under the sun but I've never had a problem like this.

Eclipse 3.52, target is Android 2.2 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the top-level view, would `View.getRootView()` give you what you need?

Comment: No, because I want to walk up the hierarchy level by level and display each view-class object as I go along.   So I don't want to "get" the root view, I just want to know when I'm there, i.e., I want to know when I've reached the top.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Would it work, then, instead of using isinstance to compare the hierarchy as you go to the root view: view.getParent().equals(originalView.getRootView())?

Comment: I'vwe devided to do a getRootView() before I start walking the tree, and then as I get each higher parent I compare it to that to see when I'm at the top, essentially what you're describing above.  I've tested it and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class `ViewRoot` that you can import.

Answer (score 1):

As @Phillip Fitzsimmons said, you probably want this method:

```
View.getRootView()
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView%28%29)

The class ViewRoot does exist, but you cannot access it from the android sdk. I'm not sure why. You can see its code [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/view/ViewRoot.java.shtml).

UPDATE: Response to comment. You could traverse the parents like this

```
Log.d(TAG, "traversing parents of " + currentView);
ViewParent vp = currentView.getParent();
View rootView = currentView.getRootView();
while (vp != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Parent: " + vp);
    vp = vp.getParent();
    if (vp.equals(rootView))
        break;
}
```

Comment: The class is part of the framework and not part of the public SDK so normal apps can't use it.

Comment: There are examples all over of people importing it   I Googled "import android.view.ViewRoot;" and got over 100K hits.    I want to walk up the hierarchy level by level and display each view-class object as I go along.   So I don't want to get the root view, I just want to know when I'm there, i.e., when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

android.view.ViewRoot appears to have been deprecated at some point. It was in (at least) Build 1.0 r1 (http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/view/ViewRoot.html) and appears to have still been present in Gingerbread (http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/index.html, see ViewRoot link in android.view package). It was certainly gone by Lollipop though (and probably much earlier).
...
Update: I just checked grepcode.com and it showed android.view.ViewRoot as being present first in 1.5_r4 and last in 2.3.7_r1.